# How to put Input on next line in Java's Scanner utility

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, println

I have a basic java question about the scanner utility.  Let's say i have a simple program that takes the user input and stores it in a variable.  My question is when i run the program that asks for multiple inputs, the cursor starts at the beginning of the question and not after it.
     My code is:

```
public class question3 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter the first number:");
       Float a = s.nextFloat();
       System.out.println("Enter the second number:");
       Float b = s.nextFloat();
       System.out.println("Sum = " + (a+b));
       System.out.println("Difference = " + (a-b));
       System.out.println("Product = " + (a*b));


       }
}
```

When I run this program it will look like Enter First Number then i type the number, and then |Enter Second Number.  "|" meaning where the blinking cursor is.  When I type it'll show up underneath, but it could confuse the user so I was wondering what the solution could be.

[image]

It is an IDE problem, since nothing else is wrong with the code.

Comment: It's an issue with the IDE. Your program looks perfect. Adding \n, might, may be make it better, but cursor blinking is an IDE thing.

Comment: @Vijairam ya i think it is. I dont see any other problem or solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `println(String)` before each input, change it to `print(String)`. So it would look something like this:

```
public class question3{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the first number:");
        Float a = s.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number:");
        Float b = s.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Sum = " + (a+b));
        System.out.println("Difference = " + (a-b));
        System.out.println("Product = " + (a*b));


    }
}
```

Also, just a note, you should use proper/appropriate naming conventions for your variables. Like for your `Scanner`, you should call it `reader` or `input`; something which represents its function. The same idea goes for the rest of your variables. Also, class names start with a capital.

Here is what the finished result looks like:

[image]

Comment: does  s.nextFloat(); make a new line for you?

Comment: @ns47731 Well judging from the image (using IntelliJ), it would appear so.

Comment: @JoshM thanks for your reply but my problem seems to be with the cursor blinking, the program puts the number in the correct place but in the display it shows the cursor blink at the beginning of the question. Can you visualize that? or should i maybe take a picture of it?

Comment: @VrnRap I think it really depends on which IDE you're using. Sure, update your question with a picture. It sounds like you're using Dr. Java in which case I believe you could just click to where the input would normally be and the caret will move there.

Comment: @JoshM ya it does move to the correct location when i press or type just a visual thing. i guess its no big deal.

Answer (score 2):

System.out.println prints out string then a new line, so your input is being placed on a new line. Try making it read

```
System.out.print("Enter the first number:");
Float a = s.nextFloat();
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Enter the second number:");
Float b = s.nextFloat();
System.out.println();
```

Comment: It essentially the same problem because its not the program's issue. Maybe it because of Eclipse i dont know but its the Cursor thats still blinking in a different spot and not where its supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

This can save you some seconds, by typing few lines:

```
System.out.print("Enter the first number:");
Float a = s.nextFloat();
System.out.print("\nEnter the second number:");
Float b = s.nextFloat();
System.out.println("\nSum = " + (a+b)
                   +"\nDifference = " + (a-b)
                   +"\nProduct = " + (a*b));
```